# Installing required libs/frameworks/packages for compilation on OSX

Tags: osx, compiling, path, libraries, configure

I'm trying to compile [SmartSim](https://github.com/ashleynewson/SmartSim) for OSX Lion, and at the moment I'm at the `./configure` stage.

Here is a dump of what I've managed to get so far:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0) were not met:

Package 'cairo', required by 'pangocairo', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

However, I have installed Homebrew, and it says I have the above installed:

```
$ brew install gtk+
Warning: gtk+-2.24.17 already installed
```

Here's a dump of my `/etc/paths` file:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/Frameworks/GTK+.framework/Resources/bin
```

Oh, and I have XCode installed for the compiler collection, build tools, and all the other dev tools.

So, how do I get the configure script to recognize that I have the required pkgs/libs/frmwrks installed?

Comment: Try installing pango and libpango.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried installing those and it (homebrew) says they're installed.

Comment: You've got the header libraries installed for gtk+ too then? Not sure of the package name on OSX but on Linux they're called, gtk+-devel.

Comment: Oops... Totally forgot about those devel libs. I'll try those. Yeah, I'm used to Linux, and I usually just use mu Mac for games and browsing, so it was new to me...

I'll see how it goes though.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be headers in the repo... Do you know ehre I could get them for OSX or how I could compile and install them myself?

Comment: No I don't have OSX. I'm wondering if your brew install is borked. Can you read through this thread and try some of the tips regarding fixing brew + gtk+? https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13546

Comment: Well, the thing is, I just installed brew when I found out I needed these libs, so I doubt it's borked.